# SolR WildCard Searching with keywords

Tags: solr

I have a requirement in SolR, to search the index data with keywords. e.g., in google.

Lets say I have field in below with firstName+LastName+CampanyName+Address

E.g., James Madison Stark Industries 1024 33rd St,Mahattan Newyork NY 07211

I am storing such data in field named "id", with below configuration in schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="c_text" class="solr.TextField">
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>

<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Now my requirement is to get above field when I do queries like

id:*jam madi*
id:*James*Stark*
id:*Madison*NY*

Due to some reason, It doesnt work. Please advice.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your approach and in your query.

1. `id:jam madi` will run a query like this: `id:jam OR default:madi` where default is your default field defined in your schema.
2. leading wildcard search does not work by default in Solr
3. I think the query `id:*James*Stark*` need to be dividid into 2 queries like this: `id:*James* id:*Stark*` (the leading wildcard whould not work though)